# C# Update Excel Using Oledb datagridview

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, oledb

```
namespace PROCESS_FOLDER_V2
{
    public partial class OrganiZe : Form
    {
        public OrganiZe()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }


    int TotalCnt = 0;

    private void Insert(int Col1, string Col2, string Col3, string Col4, int Col5)
    {

        // MessageBox.Show("SNo: " + Col1 + "\n"+"\n" + "Material Code " + Col2 + "\n"+"\n" + "Item Text :" + Col3 +"\n"+"\n"+ "PO Text :" + Col4 + "\n"+"\n"+"PR Number :" + Col5, "OrganiZe");
        while (Col4.Contains("'"))
        {
            Col4 = Col4.Replace("'", "`");
        };
        while (Col3.Contains("'"))
        {
            Col3 = Col3.Replace("'", "`");
        };
        //File.WriteAllText("Char.txt", Col4);
        //MessageBox.Show("SNo: " + Col1 + "\n" + "\n" + "Material Code " + Col2 + "\n" + "\n" + "Item Text :" + Col3 + "\n" + "\n" + "PO Text :" + Col4 + "\n" + "\n" + "PR Number :" + Col5, "OrganiZe");

        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand myCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
        string sql = null;
        MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=e:\PRTEXT.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0");
        MyConnection.Open();

        myCommand.Connection = MyConnection;
        sql = "INSERT INTO [PR$]"
            + "([SNo],[MATERIAL CODE],[ITEM TEXT],[PO TEXT],[PRNo])"
            + "VALUES('" + Col1 + "','" + Col2 + "','" + Col3 + "','" + Col4 + "','" + Col5 + "')";

        myCommand.CommandText = sql;
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        OleDbDataAdapter da;
        da = new OleDbDataAdapter(myCommand);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Update(dt);
        // da.Fill(ds);
        //dgPR.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        MyConnection.Close();

    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //  READ TEXT FILE

    string PRtext = "";
    string PRtextEdited = "";

    //***************************************************************
    private void ReadPDF(string getName)
    {
        string strText = null;
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(getName);

        for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
        {
            ITextExtractionStrategy its = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
            string s = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, page, its);
            s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(s)));
            strText = strText + s;
            // txtFilee.Text = strText;

        }

        PRtext = strText;
        reader.Close();
        //StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("PDFtoTEXT.txt");
        File.WriteAllText("PDFtoText.txt", PRtext);
        //sw.Close();

        string lRead;
        lRead = strText;
        txtFilee.Text = strText;

        int IndPrvPage = 0;
        int len = 113;
        //string Page = "";
        if (lRead.Contains("'")) { lRead = lRead.Replace("'", "`"); };
        int IndPage = lRead.IndexOf("Page", IndPrvPage);

        while (lRead.Contains("Page") == true)
        {
            if (lRead.Length < (lRead.IndexOf("Page", 0) + len)) { break; }

            IndPage = lRead.IndexOf("Page", IndPrvPage);

            //Page = lRead.Substring(IndPage, len);
            //string temp;
            if (IndPage > 0) { lRead = lRead.Remove(IndPage, len); };
            if (IndPage < 0) { break; };

            IndPrvPage = IndPage;
            //MessageBox.Show(Page);


        }
        //MessageBox.Show(lRead);
        File.WriteAllText("PDFtoTEXT.txt", lRead);
        PRtextEdited = lRead;
        //MessageBox.Show(PRtextEdited);
    }
    //*******************************************************







    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // FINDING AND ORGANIZING



    private void btnOrganize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        fbd.ShowDialog();
        string NameFolder = fbd.SelectedPath;


        foreach (string getName in Directory.GetFiles(@NameFolder, "*.pdf"))
        {
            ReadPDF(getName);

            int IndInitial = 0;
            int index = 0;
            string tmp = "";

            //*****************

            tmp = PRtextEdited;

            //***********************
            ///find PR No.
            int PRNo = 0;
            int IndPRNo = 0;
            string PRNum;
            IndPRNo = tmp.IndexOf("Purchase Requisition") + 23;
            PRNum = tmp.Substring(IndPRNo, 9);
            // MessageBox.Show("Purchase Requisition No: " + PRNum, "OrganiZe");

            int Finish = 0;
            // string Zeros="000";
            string Zeros3 = "000";
            string Zeros2 = "00";
            string Zeros1 = "0";
            int N = 10;
            string ItemNo = "00000";
            string NxtItemNo = "00000";
            int Cnt = 0;
            string z = "MATERIAL DESCRIPTION & ITEM TEXT";
            int IndZ = 0;
            if ((tmp.IndexOf(z) < 0)) { z = "N & ITEM TEXT"; }
            IndZ = tmp.IndexOf(z, IndInitial) + 25;             // set starting index as MATERIAL DESCRIPTION & ITEM TEXT


            //MessageBox.Show(tmp);
            do
            {
                string txtFindPO = "Material  PO Text";
                string txtFindITEM = "Item Text";
                string txtLast = "Prepared By";
                string matCode = "";
                int indMat = 0;
                int indPO = 0, indItem = 0, indNext = 0;


                if (N < 100) { ItemNo = Zeros3 + N.ToString(); }
                if (N >= 100 && N < 1000) { ItemNo = Zeros2 + N.ToString(); }
                if (N >= 1000 && N < 10000) { ItemNo = Zeros1 + N.ToString(); }

                //find first item
                string Item = ItemNo + " " + "M";

                while (tmp.IndexOf(Item, IndZ) == -1)
                {
                    N = N + 10;

                    if (N < 100) { ItemNo = Zeros3 + N.ToString(); }
                    if (N >= 100 && N < 1000) { ItemNo = Zeros2 + N.ToString(); }
                    if (N >= 1000 && N < 10000) { ItemNo = Zeros1 + N.ToString(); }
                    Item = ItemNo + " " + "M";


                }

                if (N < 90) { NxtItemNo = Zeros3 + (N + 10).ToString(); }
                if (N >= 90 && N < 990) { NxtItemNo = Zeros2 + (N + 10).ToString(); }
                if (N >= 990 && N < 9990) { NxtItemNo = Zeros1 + (N + 10).ToString(); }


                index = tmp.IndexOf(Item, IndZ);

                indMat = index;

                indPO = tmp.IndexOf(txtFindPO, index);
                if (indPO >= 0) { indPO = indPO + 43; };


                indItem = tmp.IndexOf(txtFindITEM, index);
                if (indItem >= 0) { indItem = indItem + 9; };
                //find next item
                string NxtItem = NxtItemNo + " " + "M";


                while (tmp.IndexOf(NxtItem, IndZ) == -1)
                {
                    N = N + 10;

                    if (N < 90) { NxtItemNo = Zeros3 + (N + 10).ToString(); }
                    if (N >= 90 && N < 990) { NxtItemNo = Zeros2 + (N + 10).ToString(); }
                    if (N >= 990 && N < 9990) { NxtItemNo = Zeros1 + (N + 10).ToString(); }

                    NxtItem = NxtItemNo + " " + "M";

                    indNext = tmp.IndexOf(NxtItem, index);
                    if (N >= 990)
                    {
                        int IndLast = 0;
                        IndLast = tmp.IndexOf("Prepared By", 0);
                        IndLast = tmp.IndexOf(txtLast, index);
                        indNext = IndLast;
                        Finish++;
                        break;
                    };


                }

                if (Finish < 1)
                {
                    if (N < 90) { NxtItemNo = Zeros3 + (N + 10).ToString(); }
                    if (N >= 90 && N < 990) { NxtItemNo = Zeros2 + (N + 10).ToString(); }
                    if (N >= 990 && N < 9990) { NxtItemNo = Zeros1 + (N + 10).ToString(); }

                    NxtItem = NxtItemNo + " " + "M";
                    indNext = tmp.IndexOf(NxtItem, index);

                }


                //**********************

                int lenITEM = 0;
                int lenPO = 0;
                string POtxt = "";
                string ITEMtxt = "";


                if (indPO > 0 && indItem > 0) { lenPO = (indItem - indPO) - 9; };
                if (indPO > 0 && indItem < 0) { lenPO = indNext - indPO - 9; };

                if (indItem > 0 && indNext > 0) { lenITEM = (indNext - indItem); }


                if (lenPO > 255) { lenPO = 255; }
                if (lenPO < 0) { lenPO = 0; }

                matCode = tmp.Substring(indMat + 6, 11);                  //material code


                if (indPO > 0) { POtxt = tmp.Substring(indPO, lenPO); };                    //MessageBox.Show(POtxt);

                if (lenITEM > 255) { lenITEM = 255; }
                if (lenITEM < 0) { lenITEM = 0; }

                if (indItem > 0) { ITEMtxt = tmp.Substring(indItem, lenITEM); };              //MessageBox.Show(ITEMtxt);


                Cnt = Cnt + 1;

                PRNo = Convert.ToInt32(PRNum);

                Insert(Cnt, matCode, ITEMtxt, POtxt, PRNo);   // INSERT INTO TABLE


                if (Finish == 1) break;

                N = N + 10;


            } while (N <= 990);
            //sr.Close();




            TotalCnt++;



            //  MessageBox.Show("All Organized", "OrganiZe");
            // MessageBox.Show("Total Items Nos: " + Cnt.ToString(), "OrganiZe");

        }

        MessageBox.Show("All completed.  " + "\n" + "\n" + "No of PR processed: " + TotalCnt.ToString(), "OrganiZe");
    }
















    private void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connetionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=e:\PRTEXT.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0";

        string sql = "SELECT * FROM [PR$]";
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connetionString);
        connection.ConnectionString = connetionString;
        adap = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        connection.Open();
        adap.Fill(ds);
        dgPR.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        connection.Close();
    }











    private void txtFilter_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conn = new OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=e:\PRTEXT.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0";
        conn.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        //cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [PR$] WHERE [MATERIAL CODE] LIKE ('" + txtFilter.Text + "%')";

        /*  if (cbFilter.SelectedItem.ToString() == "ITEM TEXT")
          {
              cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [PR$] WHERE [ITEM TEXT] LIKE ('%" + txtFilter.Text + "%')";
          }
          if (cbFilter.SelectedItem.ToString() == "PO TEXT")
          {
              cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [PR$] WHERE [PO TEXT] LIKE ('%" + txtFilter.Text + "%')";
          }
          if (cbFilter.SelectedItem.ToString() == "MATERIAL CODE")
          {
              cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [PR$] WHERE [MATERIAL CODE] LIKE ('%" + txtFilter.Text + "%')";
          }
          if (cbFilter.SelectedItem.ToString() == "PRNo")
          {
              cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [PR$] WHERE [PRNo] LIKE ('%" + txtFilter.Text + "%')";
          }

         */

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [PR$] WHERE [ITEM TEXT] LIKE ('%" + txtFilter.Text + "%')";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //OleDbDataAdapter adap = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [PR$] LIKE '"+txtFilter.Text+"%'", conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adap = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        adap.Fill(dt);
        dgPR.DataSource = dt;
        //MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString());
    }

    //OleDbDataAdapter adap = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    // DataSet ds = new DataSet(@"PRTEXT.XLS");
    // string sql;

    //DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    // OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
    // private string contents;
    // OleDbCommandBuilder builder; 

















    // }



    private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        conn = new OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=e:\PRTEXT.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0";
        conn.Open();



        string xlsSheet = "PR$";
        string name = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)dgPR.DataSource;

        string changeColumns = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < Table.ColumnName.Count; i++)
        {
            changeColumns += Table.ColumnName[i] + "=@" + Table.ColumnName[i];
            if (Table.ColumnName.Count - 1 != i)
                changeColumns += ",";
        }

        adap.UpdateCommand = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [" + xlsSheet + "]  SET " + changeColumns +
                                                            " WHERE " + Table.ColumnName[PrimaryColumnIndex] + " = @" + Table.ColumnName[PrimaryColumnIndex], conn);
        for (int i = 0; i < Table.ColumnName.Count; i++)
        {
            adap.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@" + Table.ColumnName[i], OleDbType.Char, 255).SourceColumn = Table.ColumnName[i];
        }
        foreach (int row in ListOfValues.Keys)
        {
            Table tbl = ListOfValues[row];
            ds.Tables[0].Rows[row][Table.ColumnName[PrimaryColumnIndex]] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[row][PrimaryColumnIndex];
            for (int i = 0; i < tbl.Value.Count; i++)
            {
                ds.Tables[0].Rows[row][Table.ColumnName[tbl.col[i]]] = tbl.Value[i];
            }
            //adap.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            adap.Update(ds.Tables[0]);
        }
        conn.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Updated");
    }


    bool isFormLoad = false;
    int PrimaryColumnIndex = 4;
    OleDbDataAdapter adap;
    DataSet ds;
    OleDbConnection conn;
    OleDbCommandBuilder builder;


    Dictionary<int, Table> ListOfValues = new Dictionary<int, Table>();

    public class Table
    {
        public List<string> Value { get; set; }
        public List<int> col { get; set; }
        public static List<string> ColumnName;
    }


    private void OrganiZe_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        conn = new OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=e:\PRTEXT.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0";
        conn.Open();
        adap = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [PR$]", conn);
        ds = new DataSet();
        adap.Fill(ds, "PR");
        Table.ColumnName = new List<string>();
        foreach (DataColumn str in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
        {
            Table.ColumnName.Add(str.ColumnName);
        }
        dgPR.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        conn.Close();
        dgPR.Columns[PrimaryColumnIndex].ReadOnly = true;
        dgPR.RowValidated += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dgPR_RowValidated);
        isFormLoad = true;

    }


    private void dgPR_RowValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isFormLoad)
        {
            Table tbl = new Table();
            DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
            tbl.Value = new List<string>();
            tbl.col = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 1; i < dgv.ColumnCount; i++)
            {
                tbl.Value.Add(dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[i].Value.ToString());
                tbl.col.Add(i);
            }

            if (ListOfValues.Keys.Contains(e.RowIndex))
            {
                ListOfValues[e.RowIndex] = tbl;
            }
            else
                ListOfValues.Add(e.RowIndex, tbl);
        }
    }







}
```

}

Code fucntion insert works well in excel. But code Update is not working.also I tried to run step by step..it executes all but stops at adap.update(ds.tables[0]) saying Syntax error in UPDATE statement.

```
exception: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException was unhandled
HResult=-2147217900
Message=Syntax error in UPDATE statement.
Source=Microsoft Office Access Database Engine
ErrorCode=-2147217900
```

Comment: what Data is in **PRTEXT.xls** file? Can you provide dummy data, so I can give example like tha.

Comment: I has 3 columns but no of rows are unknown. I need to update excel through datagridview. I change any cell in datagridview,it should be saved in excel after clicking update button.

Comment: can you specify? what column you want to make unchange or make primary key? column 1 or any other?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose You have following Data in your workSheet `PR`

---

```
FirstName LastName     Age
johny     Depp         55
Statham   John         45
Diana     bantley      35
```

---

then you have to go through this code in your Button Click for **Update**

```
 conn= new OleDbConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=e:\PRTEXT.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0";
    conn.Open();
    string xlsSheet = "PR$";
    adap.UpdateCommand = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [" + xlsSheet + "] SET FirstName = ?, LastName = ?, Age = ?" +

                                                    " WHERE FirstName = "+ ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0], conn);

    adap.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", OleDbType.Char, 255).SourceColumn = "FirstName";

        adap.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@LastName", OleDbType.Char, 255).SourceColumn = "LastName";

        adap.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Age", OleDbType.Char, 255).SourceColumn = "Age";

        //// Updates the first row

        ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["FirstName"] = "john";

        ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["LastName"] = "Statham";

        ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Age"] = "55";


        adap.Update(ds.Tables[0]);
        conn.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Updated");
```

where we give whole Query of update and in where condition we pass value of first index (i-e (Zero index) value) , this update value Succesfully by changing our data DataTable Zero Index row.

Comment: I need to update excel using datagridview. No of rows are unknown. No of column is three.

Comment: /I will change data in datagridview in any row of any column and after clicking update button it should update change into excel. How code will identify which cell is updated with what. can you provide code?

Comment: please provide your code? what you have done? then i can do any thing

Comment: you wanted multiple rows to be updated? or one at a time?

Comment: i can edit one or mutiple cells in datagridview and after clicking update button expecting it to update excel file..used as oledb database.

Comment: can you specify? what column you want to make unchange or make primary key? column 1 or any other?

Comment: Col1 maybe set to primary key. i dont know how to autoincrement SNo first col1 as primary key. Col2,Col3,Col4, maybe changed from datagridview. Thanks for comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full work of your given conditions, kindly check from your end.

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conn.Open();
        string xlsSheet = "PR$";
        string name = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)dgPR.DataSource;

        string changeColumns = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < Table.ColumnName.Count; i++)
        {
            changeColumns += Table.ColumnName[i] + "=@" + Table.ColumnName[i];
            if (Table.ColumnName.Count - 1 != i)
                changeColumns += ",";
        }

        adap.UpdateCommand = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [" + xlsSheet + "]  SET " + changeColumns +
                                                            " WHERE " + Table.ColumnName[PrimaryColumnIndex] + " = @" + Table.ColumnName[PrimaryColumnIndex], conn);
        for (int i = 0; i < Table.ColumnName.Count; i++)
        {
            adap.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@" + Table.ColumnName[i], OleDbType.Char, 255).SourceColumn = Table.ColumnName[i];
        }
        foreach (int row in ListOfValues.Keys)
        {
            Table tbl = ListOfValues[row];
            ds.Tables[0].Rows[row][Table.ColumnName[PrimaryColumnIndex]] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[row][PrimaryColumnIndex];
            for (int i = 0; i < tbl.Value.Count; i++)
            {
                ds.Tables[0].Rows[row][Table.ColumnName[tbl.col[i]]] = tbl.Value[i];
            }

            adap.Update(ds.Tables[0]);
        }
        conn.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Updated");
    }


    bool isFormLoad = false;
    int PrimaryColumnIndex = 0;
    OleDbDataAdapter adap;
    DataSet ds;
    OleDbConnection conn;
    OleDbCommandBuilder builder;


    Dictionary<int, Table> ListOfValues = new Dictionary<int, Table>();

    public class Table
    {
        public List<string> Value { get; set; }
        public List<int> col { get; set; }
        public static List<string> ColumnName;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conn = new OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=e:\PRTEXT.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0";
        conn.Open();
        adap = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [PR$]", conn);
        ds = new DataSet();
        adap.Fill(ds, "PR");
        Table.ColumnName = new List<string>();
        foreach (DataColumn str in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
        {
            Table.ColumnName.Add(str.ColumnName);
        }
        dgPR.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        conn.Close();
        dgPR.Columns[PrimaryColumnIndex].ReadOnly = true;
        dgPR.RowValidated += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dgPR_RowValidated);
        isFormLoad = true;

    }


    private void dgPR_RowValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isFormLoad)
        {
            Table tbl = new Table();
            DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
            tbl.Value = new List<string>();
            tbl.col = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 1; i < dgv.ColumnCount; i++)
            {
                tbl.Value.Add(dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[i].Value.ToString());
                tbl.col.Add(i);
            }

            if (ListOfValues.Keys.Contains(e.RowIndex))
            {
                ListOfValues[e.RowIndex] = tbl;
            }
            else
                ListOfValues.Add(e.RowIndex, tbl);
        }
    }
```

kindly change `PrimaryColumnIndex` which you want to be not change in Excel File.

**Update:**
 Replace `btnUpdate_Click` through this.

```
   private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conn.Open();
        string xlsSheet = "PR$";

        DataTable dt = (DataTable)dgPR.DataSource;

        string changeColumns = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < Table.ColumnName.Count; i++)
        {
            changeColumns += "[" + Table.ColumnName[i] + "]"+ "=@" + Table.ColumnName[i];
            if (Table.ColumnName.Count - 1 != i)
                changeColumns += ",";
        }

        adap.UpdateCommand = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [" + xlsSheet + "]  SET " + changeColumns +
                                                            " WHERE " + "["+ Table.ColumnName[PrimaryColumnIndex] +
                                                            "]"+ " = @" + Table.ColumnName[PrimaryColumnIndex], conn);
        for (int i = 0; i < Table.ColumnName.Count; i++)
        {
            adap.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@" + Table.ColumnName[i], OleDbType.Char, 255).SourceColumn = Table.ColumnName[i];
        }
        foreach (int row in ListOfValues.Keys)
        {
            Table tbl = ListOfValues[row];
            ds.Tables[0].Rows[row][Table.ColumnName[PrimaryColumnIndex]] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[row][PrimaryColumnIndex];
            for (int i = 0; i < tbl.Value.Count; i++)
            {
                ds.Tables[0].Rows[row][Table.ColumnName[tbl.col[i]]] = tbl.Value[i];
            }

            adap.Update(ds.Tables[0]);
        }
        conn.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Updated");
    }
```

**Update 2 :**
It is throwing error Because, <kbd>Space</kbd> is not supported in Query between Feilds Name.
Again update `btnUpdate_Click` from following Code

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conn.Open();
        string xlsSheet = "PR$";

        DataTable dt = (DataTable)dgPR.DataSource;

        string changeColumns = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < Table.ColumnName.Count; i++)
        {
            changeColumns += "[" + Table.ColumnName[i] + "]"+ "=@" + Table.ColumnName[i].Replace(' ','_');
            if (Table.ColumnName.Count - 1 != i)
                changeColumns += ",";
        }

        adap.UpdateCommand = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [" + xlsSheet + "]  SET " + changeColumns +
                                                            " WHERE " + "["+ Table.ColumnName[PrimaryColumnIndex] +
                                                            "]"+ " = @" + Table.ColumnName[PrimaryColumnIndex].Replace(' ','_'), conn);
        for (int i = 0; i < Table.ColumnName.Count; i++)
        {
            adap.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@" + Table.ColumnName[i].Replace(' ','_'), OleDbType.Char, 255).SourceColumn = Table.ColumnName[i];
        }
        foreach (int row in ListOfValues.Keys)
        {
            Table tbl = ListOfValues[row];
            ds.Tables[0].Rows[row][Table.ColumnName[PrimaryColumnIndex]] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[row][PrimaryColumnIndex];
            for (int i = 0; i < tbl.Value.Count; i++)
            {
                ds.Tables[0].Rows[row][Table.ColumnName[tbl.col[i]]] = tbl.Value[i];
            }

            adap.Update(ds.Tables[0]);
        }
        conn.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Updated");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply and soo much effort for solution. I appreciate it. But, its telling syntax error on.  adap.Update(ds.Tables[0]);

Comment: mark break point and check what Query is used by adapter?
or if ou can edit your post with latest code will be better, for understanding.

on my side this code is running Ok.

Comment: I ran step by step.all executes well but stops at adap.update(ds.Tables[0]) telling syntax error in UPDATE statement.I have edited and provided complete code here.It reads pdf,converts it and organizes it into excel. I think,there is error in UPDATE query ?

Comment: Thanks for update. still error..  Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '@MATERIAL CODE'.

Comment: @Mirror Kindly Update your code through **Update 2**, and let me know

Comment: Perfect ! It worked. Thanks a lot . Can same code be used to insert and delete also ?

Comment: @Mirror Please make this as acceptable answer so other also take advantage from this. I think it work on insert also, but not on delete, you have to select any row for deleting. and delete procedure is different from this. :-)

Comment: I changed database to access database. Its telling error :  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.   at adap.updatecommand(....)   why its not working?

Comment: change adap.UpdateCommand to instance of `OleDbCommand` and after that replace **adap.updatecommand(....)** to **OleDbCommandInstance.ExecuteNonQuery();**